# Using an array in ruby file to create radio buttons in haml view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, erb

I am creating a sample question page for a programme and haven't been able to find a solution that suits my needs, any help would be appreciated.

In my survey_handler.rb file I have the following method (partial code for examples):

```
def temp_structure   [
    { type: 'question', question_type: SurveyDefinition::QT_STRING, id: 1, editable: true, deletable: false, required: false, title: "String question", body: "with body" },
    { type: 'question', question_type: SurveyDefinition::QT_INTEGER, id: 3, editable: true, deletable: false, required: true, title: "Integer please" },
    { type: 'question', question_type: SurveyDefinition::QT_RADIO_BUTTONS, id: 7, editable: true, deletable: false, required: true, title: "Please choose one", choices: ["Yes", "No", "Don't Know"], },
```

And in my haml view I have:

```
- case question['question_type']
  - when SurveyDefinition::QT_STRING
    = f.label :data_string, survey_question_label(question['title'], question['body'], question['required']), class: "form-label"
    = f.text_field :data_string, class: "form-control", required: question['required']
  - when SurveyDefinition::QT_INTEGER
    = f.label :data_integer, survey_question_label(question['title'], question['body'], question['required']), class: "form-label"
    = f.number_field :data_integer, class: "form-control", required: question['required']
```

I've been tying to implement a standard ruby method where I iterate over the 'choices' array in QT_RADIO_BUTTONS to create each radio button but I've been running into error after error, what would be the best way to write this?

(Relatively new to ruby and haml, also first question here so any feedback about my question structure would be great)

Edit: this was the latest method I tried but I'm not sure how to point to the 'choices' array

```
  - when SurveyDefinition::QT_RADIO_BUTTONS
    .row.form-group
      = f.label :data_string, survey_question_label(question['title'], question['body'], question['required']), class: "form-label"
      = @choices.each do |choice|
        .col-1
          = f.radio_button :data_string, "#{choice}"
```

Comment: What are the errors you keep getting?

Comment: Have edited with my latest attempt at fixing it. Currently getting "a undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" because I'm not pointing to the 'choices' array correctly and not sure how to go about that

Comment: unless you're on an old version of rails, the `= @choices...` should be `- @choices...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you need `choices: ["Yes", "No", "Don't Know"]`. So to use then in view:

```
- question['choices'].each do |choice|
  .col-1
    = f.radio_button :data_string, choice
```

Additionaly, no need to use string interpolation `#{choice}` because choices already are strings.

Comment: @alexjohnston if answer worked, please, upvote and accept it.

Comment: I can't upvote unfortunately (zero reputation) but have accepted